# Can't entirely wrap a div around floating div even after gving a clearer

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a wrapper div around three float div, I want to wrap the wrapper around these divs,but I can't completely wrap them, I have given a top :25px to the floating div ,so this div overflow exacltly 25 px below the wrapper,

Here is my page http://jsfiddle.net/vpcxP/ ,see how floating div overflow the main container div at the bottom

PS:I don' t want to give overflow:hidden

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding padding to the bottom of #mainContainer?

Answer (score 0):

For #mainContainer instead of height:auto use overflow:auto

```
#mainContainer
{
overflow:auto;
width: 835px;
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative;
top:50px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image:url("Images/mainContainerBG.jpg");
box-shadow: 3px 10px  20px 5px #000;
```

}

you also may need to adjust the width. Set it around 900px.
You seem to have redefined style for .column. remove that property and use this for column.

```
.column
{
width:280px;
height:452px;
top:25px;
float:left;
left:5px;
box-shadow:3px 10px 7px 3px #4f4848;
background-color:#2c2b2b;
margin-left:5px;

}
```